# Eliminating NULL values from the UNION set operators

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, union, sql-null

How should we need to eliminate NULL values rather than keeping it in separate rows, values must need to reside in a column, thus by making the NULL values to disappear, by making use of a union set operator from the executed result sets?

Consider the simple SQL query

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    (SELECT
      6 + 2 AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      6 - 2 AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      6 * 2 AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      6 / 2 AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
  ) A;
```

**Actual Result:**

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| addition | subtraction | multiplication | division |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+
|        8 |        NULL |          NULL  |     NULL |
|     NULL |           4 |          NULL  |     NULL |
|     NULL |        NULL |            12  |     NULL |
|     NULL |        NULL |          NULL  |   3.0000 |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+
| addition | subtraction | multiplication | division |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+
|        8 |           4 |          12    |   3.0000 |
+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

### [SQL Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d6c92a711c4b096e8151222ee27142e1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT
  max(addition) as addition,max(subtraction) as subtraction, max(multiplication) as multiplication,max(division) as division
FROM
  (
    (SELECT
      6 + 2 AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      6 - 2 AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      6 * 2 AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      6 / 2 AS division
    FROM
      DUAL)
  ) A;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do.

```
SELECT
 sum(isnull(addition,0)) addition
 ,sum(isnull(subtraction,0)) subtraction
 ,sum(isnull(multiplication,0)) multiplication
 ,sum(isnull(division,0)) division
FROM
  (
    (SELECT
      6 + 2 AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      6 - 2 AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      6 * 2 AS multiplication,
      NULL AS division
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT
      NULL AS addition,
      NULL AS subtraction,
      NULL AS multiplication,
      6 / 2 AS division
    )
  ) A
```

Comment: Will, you try to run your above query [Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=a600ca3424684d3e3d2a80174a338a3a) . Since results in Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'

Comment: Good, so your query turns to be like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=4080bca88f61eab688de28a9fbbea836)